# What is the wrong with my padovan series code?

Tags: algorithm, numbers

I am trying to get the nth number in Padovan Sequence with the help of the Dynamic Programming. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code?

```py
def padovan(n):
    p = [1, 1, 1]
    while len(p) < n+1:
        p.append(0)
    res = sum([p[i] for i in range(3)])

    for i in range(3, n+1):
        res += p[n-2] + p[n-3]

    return res
```

It should return the right nth number but I don't know what is wrong with it.

Comment: Please tell what you get currently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't update list items and always reuse the same (zero) last items. `res` is not needed.

```
for i in range(3, n+1):
    p[i] = p[i-2] + p[i-3]

return p[n]

print(padovan(10))
>>12
```